# TensorFlow 2.0 RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0

I am just installing TensorFlow 2.0 but running into session.run issues. Everytime I execute sess.run on my code using python I get a runtime error. Code snippet:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    
sess=tf.Session()
# verify we can print a string
hello=tf.constant("Hello Pluralsight from TensorFlow")
print((hello))
    
a = tf.constant(20)
b = tf.constant(22)
z = (a + b)
    
print('a + b = {0}'.format(sess.run(z)))
```

Terminal error below:

```
    python installation_test.py
2020-11-23 22:03:21.575988: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x12c79e790 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-11-23 22:03:21.576019: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "installation_test.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(ses.run(c))
  File "/Users/evanwiley/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 960, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/evanwiley/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py", line 1106, in _run
    raise RuntimeError('Attempted to use a closed Session.')
RuntimeError: Attempted to use a closed Session.
```

Comment: You should try with a newer version of python. 2.7 has reached its end-of-life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything that uses tf.Session has to be with the namespace where session is active, in your case you need the following would be change:

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
    
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # verify we can print a string
    hello=tf.constant("Hello, TensorFlow")
    print((hello))
    
    a = tf.constant(20)
    b = tf.constant(22)
    z = (a + b)
    
    print('a + b = {0}'.format(sess.run(z)))
```

When you try to do sess.run outside the scope, it automatically closes the session.